# Sandboxed app with Helper app

Tags: macos, swift, sandbox, smjobbless

I'm trying to execute helper app from sandboxed application, but its throwing error errAuthorizationDenied (-60005), I'm using Apple [SMJobBless](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/samplecode/SMJobBless/Introduction/Intro.html) as example. Currently I have this

```
var authItem: AuthorizationItem = AuthorizationItem(name: kAuthorizationRightExecute, valueLength: 0, value: nil, flags: 0)
var authRights: AuthorizationRights = AuthorizationRights(count: 1, items: &authItem)
let authFlags: AuthorizationFlags = AuthorizationFlags.ExtendRights
var result = false
var authRef: AuthorizationRef = nil

let status: OSStatus = AuthorizationCreate(&authRights, nil, authFlags, &authRef)
if status == errAuthorizationSuccess {
    result = SMJobBless(kSMDomainSystemLaunchd, "**helperBundleIdentifier**", authRef, nil)
}
```

Am I doing something wrong, or it isn't possible in sandbox?

Comment: Is your helper sandboxed as well? That sample code is from 10.6 when sandboxing didn't exists

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From Sandboxing [guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Security/Conceptual/AppSandboxDesignGuide/DesigningYourSandbox/DesigningYourSandbox.html)

> The following app behaviors are incompatible with App Sandbox:
>
> Use of Authorization Services

Answer (score 1):

Even if you weren't sandboxed, the code you wrote will fail because `kAuthorizationRightExecute` is the wrong right to be requesting authorization for. You need to request for [`kSMRightBlessPrivilegedHelper`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/servicemanagement/ksmrightblessprivilegedhelper).

Comment: This is the correct answer.  kAuthorizationRightExecute is not for installing a helper tool.